# Why am I redirected to Account/Login page when using WebApi and AspIdentityCore beside JwtBearer in dotnet 7?

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to configure my ASP.NET Core 7 Web API to use ASP.NET Core Identity as the User/Role backend and use JwtBearer as the authorization method.

This is my service configuration in the `Program.cs` file:

```cs
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 10;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ZhuPalDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidAudience = jwtSetting.ValidAudience,
            ValidIssuer = jwtSetting.ValidIssuer,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSetting.Secret))
        };
    });


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
```

When I am trying to call a Web API action method marked with `[Authorize]` using a JwtToken retrieved from the login endpoint, I get a http 404 response code.

After looking into my HTTP client(Postman/Insomnia) I found that I was being redirected to the `Account/Login` page and after that because of the absence of the redirected page server returned a 404 error to the client.

This is whole the client log:

```
Preparing request to http://localhost:5158/Profile/extra-data
* Current time is 2023-09-18T16:23:46.327Z
* Enable automatic URL encoding
* Using default HTTP version
* Enable timeout of 100000ms
* Enable SSL validation
* Enable cookie sending with jar of 25 cookies
* Found bundle for host localhost: 0x60c037228e0 [serially]
* Can not multiplex, even if we wanted to!
* Re-using existing connection! (#19) with host localhost
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5158 (#19)

> POST /Profile/extra-data HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5158
> User-Agent: insomnia/2023.3.0
> Cookie: oc6a5ui45zxj=l3dlncv9e1unk3756a0mfpm3la; ocqwk92njrjy=u3p42et9pvi3s84asbni3j2fh8; ocbms528iyn8=4ev2l2617v2eqhjdqlgehl7jm9; ocdrufwwtp37=sbiaak1e2knc48vslao2teqggs; ocge53hr7oxy=pnp681o4o509gc1ek909r0ocpt; ocozidua8aza=5tm1g0s70v69efhtcv8vvuvofh; ochrgckw3sfb=db1q3apkm7g34u5cqrlg7qtjql; ocw0k0k41r51=4q8g84fqi3s0jg4kc932jr5su0; ocg8vzbai0el=e4q8j7882pdmpalh93487jhic1; ocp6kao2et7b=etpk6f1tgvpgbaup7mlpjhtuvb; ock9akyrf9an=phh7r315quuejt0nve2smtpa1n; oc9f2lksuaal=1pofgkelnpj2o72r3nq3cnoqte; ocxougkoe4sh=hu5ve2k0i03jvoobct7h7gapfk; oci50bcnk8nq=gjjhcavr17mcff3vadvjdn47uk; ocp9eud6ezkt=u2b56ls1bpt8d57vcloe1c6q0m; ocvzvyc9ti1g=3ke8v4tvguika5b618elqodovu
> accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsInNpZCI6IjAyMTc0Y2Yw4oCTOTQxMuKAkzRjZmUtYWZiZi01OWY3MDZkNzJjZjYiLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJhZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTY5NTA1NDIwMCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0MjAwIn0.ev3ZqESXprt-6Tu2kO__dG1cb69N0cADCzyFw_4UDGU
> Content-Length: 177

| {
|   "profileId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
|   "extraData": {
|     "additionalProp1": "string",
|     "additionalProp2": "string",
|     "additionalProp3": "string"
|   }
| }

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse

< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Mon, 18 Sep 2023 16:23:45 GMT
< Server: Kestrel
< Location: http://localhost:5158/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FProfile%2Fextra-data


* Connection #19 to host localhost left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://localhost:5158/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FProfile%2Fextra-data'
* Switch from POST to GET
* Found bundle for host localhost: 0x60c037228e0 [serially]
* Can not multiplex, even if we wanted to!
* Re-using existing connection! (#19) with host localhost
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5158 (#19)

> GET /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FProfile%2Fextra-data HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5158
> User-Agent: insomnia/2023.3.0
> Cookie: oc6a5ui45zxj=l3dlncv9e1unk3756a0mfpm3la; ocqwk92njrjy=u3p42et9pvi3s84asbni3j2fh8; ocbms528iyn8=4ev2l2617v2eqhjdqlgehl7jm9; ocdrufwwtp37=sbiaak1e2knc48vslao2teqggs; ocge53hr7oxy=pnp681o4o509gc1ek909r0ocpt; ocozidua8aza=5tm1g0s70v69efhtcv8vvuvofh; ochrgckw3sfb=db1q3apkm7g34u5cqrlg7qtjql; ocw0k0k41r51=4q8g84fqi3s0jg4kc932jr5su0; ocg8vzbai0el=e4q8j7882pdmpalh93487jhic1; ocp6kao2et7b=etpk6f1tgvpgbaup7mlpjhtuvb; ock9akyrf9an=phh7r315quuejt0nve2smtpa1n; oc9f2lksuaal=1pofgkelnpj2o72r3nq3cnoqte; ocxougkoe4sh=hu5ve2k0i03jvoobct7h7gapfk; oci50bcnk8nq=gjjhcavr17mcff3vadvjdn47uk; ocp9eud6ezkt=u2b56ls1bpt8d57vcloe1c6q0m; ocvzvyc9ti1g=3ke8v4tvguika5b618elqodovu
> accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsInNpZCI6IjAyMTc0Y2Yw4oCTOTQxMuKAkzRjZmUtYWZiZi01OWY3MDZkNzJjZjYiLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJhZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTY5NTA1NDIwMCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0MjAwIn0.ev3ZqESXprt-6Tu2kO__dG1cb69N0cADCzyFw_4UDGU

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse

< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Mon, 18 Sep 2023 16:23:45 GMT
< Server: Kestrel


* Connection #19 to host localhost left intact
```

My questions are:

1. Why is my Web API ignoring my `Authorization` header?
2. Why am I getting redirected to a login page instead of a 401 error despite my application being a Web API application?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let either of the "asp.net core identity" or "jwt" to pass authentication to request api, you could add the following policy configuration.

```
//Add a policy called "Jwt_Or_Identity" to allow either jwt or Identity.
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Jwt_Or_Identity", policy =>
    {
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

    });
});
```

On top of controller or Action to set `[Authorize()]` attribute.

```
        [Authorize(Policy = "Jwt_Or_Cookie")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {...}
```

(You could check the source code of `AddIdentity` to confirm it's scheme name is `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme`)

Explaination about redirect to `Account\login`: 
ASP.NET Core Identity is for MVC. It also comes with a set of authentication related pages. So when you create MVC, there's an option "individual accounts". for auto-generate "asp.net core identity" 
[image]
But when you create Web API, there's no such option. Because it is assumed people won't use this kind of "UI" login for back-end. But you could still force to use the "asp.net core identity" in api project.

You have add the `builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>`, but the pages are not generated.  `Account/Login` is the default login page for this method. When no user log in, the 401 will cause a redirect to the login page.
You could manually generate the log in page by following:
right click project->add->new scaffolded item
[image]
Choose identity and add
[image]
Check the `Account/login` page and add ( You need to fill `ApplicationUser` `ZhuPalDbContext` for context and user here)
[image]